# Cannot activate Java SE features in Netbeans 18

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I upgraded my Netbeans to version 18, yet I cannot activate **Java SE** and **Java Web & EE** features from the plugins dialog.
This instalation is configured to use Liberica JDK 8.

[image]

Comment: The Apache NetBeans 19 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11, 17 and 20. Therefore: update your JDK.

Comment: The most recent release that supports JDK 8 is 12.5. It is unsupported, but you can [download it from the NetBeans Archive](https://netbeans.apache.org/front/main/download/archive/). Otherwise use JDK11+. Of course you can still build JDK8 projects using JDK11. It's a shame that NetBeans doesn't give you an explicit error such as _"NetBeans 18 requires JDK11+ to function correctly"_ when you start it.

Comment: I change the conf file to use JDK 17 as default platform and that solved my problem as you (both) suggested. Now I have nothing else but thank you!

Comment: @JorgeEscamilla It's good that you have resolved your issue. Please consider posting your own answer and accepting it. Having the resolution in an accepted answer is more helpful to the community than having it in a comment.